How to Get or Print or Plot exact Open trade entry price where crossover conditions are true , not close price of bar
How to Get Exact Trade Price where all crossover are true?
I am trying it but every time it shows close price and after that bar close it shows close price of that bar, whenever crossover happen it shows price but it keep moving along with close price of bar and after exit of that bar it shows close price of that bar
if (not inLong) and long_entry_condition
    entry_price := close  // Set entry price
    label.new(x=bar_index, y=low - atr_val, text="Entry Price: " + str.tostring(entry_price), style=label.style_label_up, color=color.rgb(76, 165, 175), textcolor=color.white, size=size.tiny)
    strategy.entry("Long Entry", strategy.long, qty=25)
    // Set stop loss price to the low of the previous bar


You are using market orders. So, it will enter a trade once the bar is closed or on the open of the next bar depending on your setup.
If you want to enter a trade at a specific price, you should use limit orders. You can do that with the stop or limit arguments of the strategy.entry().
Regardless of your entry type, you can get the entry price with strategy.opentrades.entry_price(strategy.opentrades - 1)

Limit = close or limit = open does not work for this and
strategy.opentrades.entry_price(strategy.opentrades - 1) is showing very first entry price of rade open ,, i.e first trad price

You must be doing something wrong. Please share a Minimal, Reproducible Example.
